# Java.Lang.RuntimeException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat= (has extras) }

Tags: exception, android-intent, xamarin.android

This is my below code issue happens to navigate browser side

```
await Browser.OpenAsync(https://www.yyy.com, BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);
```

pasted below in stack trace

"stackTrace": "  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method,
Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0006e] in :0 \n  at
Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeAbstractVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self,
Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00014] in :0 \n  at AndroidX.Browser.CustomTabs.CustomTabsIntent.LaunchUrl (Android.Content.Context context, Android.Net.Uri url) [0x00053] in <9438f96c1dab498fbf52645fed854bcc>:0 \n  at Xamarin.Essentials.Browser.PlatformOpenAsync (System.Uri uri, Xamarin.Essentials.BrowserLaunchOptions options) [0x00113] in :0 \n  at Xamarin.Essentials.Browser.OpenAsync (System.Uri uri, Xamarin.Essentials.BrowserLaunchOptions options) [0x00006] in :0 \n  at Xamarin.Essentials.Browser.OpenAsync (System.Uri uri, Xamarin.Essentials.BrowserLaunchMode launchMode) [0x0000d] in :0 \n  at  [0x00014] in <6e31dbe00f134cddbd6acb93dc0d515f>:0 \n  --- End of managed Java.Lang.RuntimeException stack trace ---\nandroid.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://www.yyy.com/... (has extras) }\n\tat
android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2022)\n\tat
android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1677)\n\tat android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4696)\n\tat
androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:584)\n\tat android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4654)\n\tat androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:570)\n\tat android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5015)\n\tat androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity(ContextCompat.java:251)\n\tat androidx.browser.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent.launchUrl(CustomTabsIntent.java:376)\n\tat crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.InnerGestureListener.n_onSingleTapUp(Native Method)\n\tat crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.InnerGestureListener.onSingleTapUp(InnerGestureListener.java:79)\n\tat android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:669)\n\tat crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.n_dispatchTouchEvent(Native Method)\n\tat crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.dispatchTouchEvent(Platform_DefaultRenderer.java:56)\n\tat android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)\n\tat android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)\n\tat crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.VisualElementRenderer_1.n_dispatchTouchEvent(Native Method)\n\tat crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.VisualElementRenderer_1.dispatchTouchEvent(VisualElementRenderer_1.java:68)\n\tat android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)\n\tat android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)\n\tat crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.n_dispatchTouchEvent(Native Method)\n\tat crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.dispatchTouchEvent(Platform_DefaultRenderer.java:56)\n\tat android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)\n\tat android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)\n\tat crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.n_dispatchTouchEvent(Native Method)\n\tat crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.dispatchTouchEvent(Platform_DefaultRenderer.java:56)\n\tat android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)\n\tat android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)\n\tat android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)\n\tat android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)\n\tat android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)\n\tat android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)\n\tat crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.n_dispatchTouchEvent(Native Method)\n\tat crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.dispatchTouchEvent(Platform_DefaultRenderer.java:56)\n\tat android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)\n\tat android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)\n\tat crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.VisualElementRenderer_1.n_dispatchTouchEvent(Native Method)\n\tat crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.VisualElementRenderer_1.dispatchTouchEvent(VisualElementRenderer_1.java:68)\n\tat android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)\n\tat android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)\n\tat android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)\n\tat android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)\n\tat crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.VisualElementRenderer_1.n_dispatchTouchEvent(Native Method)\n\tat crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.VisualElementRenderer_1.dispatchTouchEvent(VisualElementRenderer_1.java:68)\n\tat android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)\n\tat android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)\n\tat crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.PlatformRenderer.n_dispatchTouchEvent(Native Method)\n\tat crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.PlatformRenderer.dispatchTouchEvent(PlatformRenderer.java:47)\n\tat android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)\n\tat android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)\n\tat android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)\n\tat android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)\n\tat android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)\n\tat android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)\n\tat android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)\n\tat android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)\n\tat android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)\n\tat android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)\n\tat android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)\n\tat android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)\n\tat com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:734)\n\tat com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1880)\n\tat android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3494)\n\tat androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)\n\tat androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)\n\tat com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:692)\n\tat android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:13721)\n\tat android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6200)\n\tat android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5978)\n\tat android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5427)\n\tat android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5480)\n\tat android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5446)\n\tat android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5605)\n\tat android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5454)\n\tat android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5662)\n\tat android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5427)\n\tat android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5480)\n\tat android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5446)\n\tat android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5454)\n\tat android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5427)\n\tat android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8504)\n\tat android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:8424)\n\tat android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8377)\n\tat android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8619)\n\tat android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:198)\n\tat android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)\n\tat android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)\n\tat android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:181)\n\tat android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7156)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)\n\tat com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)\n\tat com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)\n",

Comment: I have check the code you provided with the uri `https://www.google.com/` and it works. According to the error message, any code you used with `Intent.ActionView`?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT My uri also works well, it occurs some users  and also am not using Intent.ActionView

Comment: Is there any way to be able to reproduce this issue?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT not able to recreate this issue

Comment: It is hard for me to confirm what cause this issue without more details.